# Computing percentiles when given a distribution

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a vector of values, and a vector of probabilities. I want to compute the percentile over the values, but using the given vector of probabilities.

Say, for example,

```
import numpy as np
vector = np.array([4, 2, 3, 1])
probs = np.array([0.7, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
```

Ignoring `probs`, `np.percentile(vector, 10)` gives me `1.3`. However, it's clear that the lowest 10% here have value of `1`, so that would be my desired output.

**If the result lies between two data points, I'd prefer linear interpolation as [documented for the original percentile function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html)**.

How would I solve this in Python most conveniently? As in my example, `vector` will not be sorted. `probs` always sums to `1`. I'd prefer solutions that don't require "non-standard" packages, by any reasonable definition.

Comment: What's your desired output? Could you perhaps add that.

Comment: The kwarg [interpolation=‘nearest’](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/generated/numpy.percentile.html)

Comment: @palivek I made clear my desired output here would be `1` -- does that answer your question?

Comment: @FooBar Oh, it does. I thought that was an intermediate result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're prepared to sort your values, then you can construct an interpolating function that allows you to compute the inverse of the probability distribution. This is probably more easily done with `scipy.interpolate` than with pure `numpy` routines:

```
import scipy.interpolate
ordering = np.argsort(vector)
distribution = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(np.cumsum(probs[ordering]), vector[ordering], bounds_error=False, fill_value='extrapolate')
```

If you interrogate this distribution with the percentile (in the range 0..1), you should get the answers you want, e.g. `distribution(0.1)` gives 1.0, `distribution(0.5)` gives about 3.29.

A similar thing can be done with numpy's `interp()` function, avoiding the extra dependency on scipy, but that would involve reconstructing the interpolating function every time you want to calculate a percentile. This might be fine if you have a fixed list of percentiles that is known before you estimate the probability distribution.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use sampling via numpy.random.choice and then numpy.percentile:

```
N = 50 # number of samples to draw
samples = np.random.choice(vector, size=N, p=probs, replace=True)
interpolation = "nearest"
print("25th percentile",np.percentile(samples, 25, interpolation=interpolation),)
print("75th percentile",np.percentile(samples, 75, interpolation=interpolation),)
```

Depending on your kind of data (discrete or continuous) you may want to use different values for the `interpolation` parameter.