# Obtaining the percentile from a distribution

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy.stats

How can I obtain the percentiles (for example the mean, or the 10% and 90% percentile) of a distribution received from some program or experiments? In the sample below I generate a normal distribution just for illustration.

```
from scipy.stats import norm
x = np.linspace(1,10,1001)
count = norm.pdf(x,5,1)
```

This will be a gaussian curve (for this particular illustration case) if plotted as `plt.plot(x,count)`. Note that this is not the data points but the distribution (which you can obtain with, e.g., `x,count = plt.hist(data)`), so I can't use `p10 = np.percentile(count,10)`
but I would want something similar, such as

```
p10 = module.percentile(x,dist,10)
```

Does any of you know of such a module, or do you know of some other means of obtaining the percentile?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but `scipy.stats` distributions have `ppf` method that computes their percentiles. For example, to get the 30th percentile of the normal distribution with mean 5 and standard deviation 1 you can use:

```
from scipy.stats import norm

norm.ppf(0.3, loc=5, scale=1)
```

This gives:

```
4.475599487291959
```

Then, you can select elements of an array `x` which are in this percentile:

```
x[x < norm.ppf(0.3, loc=5, scale=1)]
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the distribution. It is obtained from experimental data. I only have it as two arrays, one for x and one for count. There is no reason to believe it is normally distributed, or any other distribution.

Comment: @F.Heath In such case you may want to have a look at answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49346906/15187728).

Comment: Thank you @bb1. That is exactly what I need.